# how to split words before and after colon in separate columns to rows in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a column [LongText] in a table and its row value is merging of all Attributes and their values. Below is the example.
Can we split colon before and after words into two columns as shown in expected result? need it in sql 2014

```
Longtext

TYPE: SOLID WEDGE 1,SOLID WEDGE 2,  VALVE SIZE: 1 IN,  PRESSURE RATING: 800 LB,  CONNECTION TYPE: SOCKET WELD,  BONNET STYLE: BOLTED
```

Expected Output into 2 columns Attribute and Value:

```
Attribute        | Value
----------------------------------------------
TYPE             | SOLID WEDGE 1,SOLID WEDGE 2
VALVE SIZE       | 1 IN
PRESSURE RATING  | 800 LB
CONNECTION TYPE  | SOCKET WELD
BONNET STYLE     | BOLTED
```

Comment: One good way to handle this would be via regular expressions.  Unfortunately, SQL Server has weak regex support, so it's not the best place to do this cleanup.  Is there any chance you could use some other tool to scrub your data before bringing it into SQL Server?

Comment: Hello Tim, can you please give some examples of regular expression

Comment: If this is a once-off data load, you could write a `while` loop that removes the first key/value pairs from the string, writes them to the new table and continues until the string is empty. Alternatively, use some other programming language with rich regex features to do the work.  (If this is _not_ a once-off data load, I don't recommend using a loop)

Comment: STRING_SPLIT() might be of use.. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @Sai Did you check my code in answer section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this can help. Also, let me know if you want me to explain the code.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM SYS.OBJECTS WHERE NAME = 'fn_GetAttributeAndValueFromLongText' AND TYPE = 'TF')
BEGIN
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.fn_GetAttributeAndValueFromLongText
END
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_GetAttributeAndValueFromLongText ( @String_LongText VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS @TBL_Attribute_Value TABLE 
(
    Attribute VARCHAR(MAX)
  , Value VARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @ATTR_VALUE_DELIMITER AS VARCHAR(MAX) = ':'

    WHILE (RTRIM(LTRIM(LEN(@String_LongText))) != 0)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @String_ATTR VARCHAR(MAX)='', @String_VALUE VARCHAR(MAX)= ''

        SELECT @String_LongText = RTRIM(LTRIM(@String_LongText))

        SELECT @String_ATTR = SUBSTRING(@String_LongText, 1,CHARINDEX(':',@String_LongText)-1)
        SELECT @String_LongText = RIGHT(@String_LongText, LEN(@String_LongText)-(LEN(@String_ATTR)+1))

        IF @String_LongText LIKE '%'+@ATTR_VALUE_DELIMITER+'%'
        BEGIN
            SELECT @String_VALUE = LEFT(SUBSTRING(@String_LongText, 1, CHARINDEX(':', @String_LongText)-1), LEN(SUBSTRING(@String_LongText, 1, CHARINDEX(':', @String_LongText)-1)) - CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@String_LongText, 1, CHARINDEX(':', @String_LongText)-1))))
            SELECT @String_LongText = RIGHT(@String_LongText, LEN(@String_LongText)-(LEN(@String_VALUE)+1))
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT @String_VALUE = @String_LongText
            SELECT @String_LongText = REPLACE(@String_LongText, @String_VALUE, '')
        END

        INSERT INTO @TBL_Attribute_Value ([Attribute], [Value])
        VALUES(RTRIM(LTRIM(@String_ATTR)), RTRIM(LTRIM(@String_VALUE))) 
    END

    RETURN
END

GO 

SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_GetAttributeAndValueFromLongText('TYPE: SOLID WEDGE 1,SOLID WEDGE 2,  VALVE SIZE: 1 IN,  PRESSURE RATING: 800 LB,  CONNECTION TYPE: SOCKET WELD,  BONNET STYLE: BOLTED')
```

Answer (score 0):

to get started wit STRING_SPLIT(), something like:

```
DECLARE @string varchar(max) = 'TYPE: SOLID WEDGE 1,SOLID WEDGE 2,  VALVE SIZE: 1 IN,  PRESSURE RATING: 800 LB .....';
DECLARE @output varchar(max) = '';
DECLARE @v varchar(max) = (SELECT TOP(1) value from string_split(@string,' '));
WHILE @v <> ''
BEGIN
    select @v;
    SET @string = (SELECT ltrim(substring(@string,LEN(@v)+1,1024)));
    select @string;
    SET @v = (SELECT TOP(1) value from string_split(@string,' '));
END
```

which gives:
[image: output of above script]

as @Tim said, the order is not guaranteed to be correct for above approach.

so, second attempt :

```
DECLARE @string varchar(max) = 'TYPE: SOLID WEDGE 1,SOLID WEDGE 2,  VALVE SIZE: 1 IN,  PRESSURE RATING: 800 LB,  CONNECTION TYPE: SOCKET WELD,  BONNET STYLE: BOLTED';
SELECT * FROM string_split(REPLACE(@string,'  ','#'),'#');
```

This hopes (='does-not-check') that there are no '#' characters in the original string.

Comment: This answer may not work properly, because `STRING_SPLIT` does not guarantee that the order of the words will be maintained.